# Pre pend all command in linux bash with another command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

Is there any way to prepend all the command that I type in bash shell with another command? For example, my network has a load balancer. So I want to prepend then with bsub.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you want like this http://superuser.com/questions/117227/a-command-before-every-bash-command ?

Comment: Please make some sense, guide us with some examples; preferably as close as possible to your real problem

Comment: Yes Jayesh, that helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial answer:

> Are you want like this [A command before every bash command](https://superuser.com/questions/117227/a-command-before-every-bash-command) ? – 
>   Jayesh